# configure wcf webapi using web.config

Tags: wcf-web-api

I'm currently configuring an existing WCF SOAP webservice to be accessible using WebApi

I have added the WebApi attributes, and the following code into global.asax:

```
  RouteTable.Routes.SetDefaultHttpConfiguration(new WebApiConfiguration() { EnableTestClient = true });
  RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<Contacts>("api/contacts/");
```

Is it possible to configure webapi using the web.config instead of these lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box, however it's not impossible to achieve using the extensability points built into WCF.